# listing all subsets of a vector for a given size

Tags: r, list, subset, enumerate

The function `choose(n,k)` tells us how many subsets of size `k` exists for a set of `n` distinct elements. Suppose I need to actually list those subsets, how I create it? in other words I'm looking for a function that accepts a vector `x` (of length `n`) and a number `k` and returns a list of vectors, each of size `k`, with subsets of `x`. the length of the list should be, of course, `choose(length(x),k)`. for example

```
enum.choose = function(x,k) {
    # implementation should go here
{

enum.choose(1:3,2)

# should be:
# [[1]]
#    1  2
# [[2]]
#    1  3
# [[3]]
#    2  3
```

Comment: `combn(1:3, 2)`. Check `? combn` for documentation.

Comment: why not make that an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT**

---

I realized that `combn(1:3, 2, simplify = FALSE)` gives you the list result you're looking for.  If @Ramnath wishes to post an answer, this one will be deleted.

```
> combn(1:3, 2, simplify = FALSE)
## [[1]]
## [1] 1 2

## [[2]]
## [1] 1 3

## [[3]]
## [1] 2 3
```

So using an `*apply` function on it will make the following function irrelevant.

---

**Original**

---

Making use of the comment from @Ramnath, your function might be something like this:

```
enum.choose <- function(x, k) {
  if(k > length(x)) stop('k > length(x)')
  if(choose(length(x), k)==1){
    list(as.vector(combn(x, k)))
  } else {
    cbn <- combn(x, k)
    lapply(seq(ncol(cbn)), function(i) cbn[,i])
  }
}
```

Test runs:

```
> enum.choose(1:3, 2)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 3
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 2 3
> enum.choose(c(1, 2, 5, 4), 3)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 5
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 1 2 4
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 1 5 4
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 2 5 4
> enum.choose(1:4, 4)
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4
> enum.choose(1:5, 6)
# Error in enum.choose(1:5, 6) : k > length(x)
```